# Keyboard not working in Terminal

Tags: command-line, keyboard

I'm using ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. Dual boot with windows 7.
But my keyboard is not working properly in terminal.
While typing, when I press up arrow key it is displaying "a" letter and when I press down arrow key it is displaying "b" letter. Please help me out.

Comment: Check to see if a 'Ctrl' key is stuck down?

Comment: No... i just bought new keyboard.. it is working properly on windows!

Answer (score 3):

This is normal behaviour if your arrow keys are not bound to any functionality. You can for example add these lines to `~/.inputrc` to search for the string before the cursor when pressing up or down:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

You'll need to log out and in again to make them take effect.

Comment: Where I'm suppose to put these commands? :O

Comment: `~/.inputrc`. It's a hidden file (hence the dot) in your home directory (hence the tilde). They are not commands, but rather configuration.

Comment: okay! How I'm suppose to work with them?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell) worked for me :

1. Open Vim editor,
2. Get the path of your home directory by typing :echo $HOME
3. Check if you have .vimrc file in $HOME location,(if you don't have create it)
4. Add the following line line to .vimrc file

   ```
   set nocompatible
   ```

   or

   ```
   set nocp
   ```